# Character with Height Shapekey does not follow Armature right

Tags: armature, bones, shape-keys, pose-mode

With this model I am working on, I wanted to make a shapekey slider to make the character shorter. I made a copy of the character, made it small, and then added the small version as a shapekey, which works exactly as intended.

[image: The shapekey works as intended, making the character and its accessories smaller.]

However, if I move anything on the character's armature, the model breaks completely if it is on its short mode.

[image: This happens regardless of what I move, be it an arm or a leg.]

What I am aiming for is to avoid having to export two distinct models, one big and one small, each with its own armature, and instead having a single model to export that can do it all. Is there any way to solve this?

In my naivety, I imagine another solution of having a second armature that manages a second mesh of the small model, but that would mean shoving a whole different model into another, basically having a 2-in-1 instead of a one-does-all. Is this also possible?

Comment: Don't make a shapekey to scale the mesh.  Instead, scale/reposition the bones in your armature.  Use the bones for big changes, the armature only for small changes.  Armature poses can be blended in via NLA.  If working in a different engine without any kind of animation blending, we'd need to know about that.

Comment: @Nathan I have the small model's original armature at hand, so I can move and scale the bones of the big model's armature to match exactly the armature of the small model.
The question still remains if the scaling and moving of the armature can be "toggled" with a shapekey. Is this where NLA comes into place? The scaling of the armature will be an animation?
And speaking of different engine, I will be using this model mainly on Unity, with my intention of exporting the model as a VRM.

Comment: You scale bones *instead* of making a shapekey.  You could potentially drive a pose from a shapekey value, in Blender, but you don't want to do that.  NLA lets you combine actions: for example, combining a scaled pose with a dance.  Don't know what VRM is, but action blending for Unity would have to be implemented in Unity, not Blender.

Comment: @Nathan I am not gonna use this model for animations in Blender or in Unity. I will use the model basically as a VR avatar, and a VRM is basically the preferred filetype for these kinds of applications. What I believe can happen is that I can make a simple 'animation' of the bone scaling to match the small model's original armature size (even if it is only for one frame), and then making the reverse of that animation so that they both work as 'toggles'.